# How can start a video programatically part of a UIWebView?

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I have a `UIWebView` and url below is loaded. How can I start programmatically **video** on it?

http://www.atv.hu/videok/video-20141102-havas-a-palyan-1-resz-2014-11-01

Answer (score 0):

[webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIWebView/stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:) should do what you need. Just figure out what javascript function will cause the video to start playing.